# the function $\phi (t)=t ^ 2$ defined by $t \in \mathbb{R}$ can be the solution of a homogeneous linear equation of order 1?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function $\phi(t) =t ^ 2$ defined by $t \in \mathbb{R}$ can be the solution of a homogeneous linear equation of order 1? and if not homogeneous?
I can't think of an example, help!

Comment: How about $\frac{1}{2}t \frac{dy}{dt} = y$?  Is that helpful?

Comment: Can you define linear eq.?